# Display all wordpress tags that contains specific word or words

Tags: wordpress, tags

How to display a list of all WordPress tags which contain the specific word or 2 words?

As an example, I need to display all the tags that contain “TV Show” and I get the list:

Friends TV Show
Breaking Bad TV Show
...

I found this code but it's not working:

```
    <?php
$tags = get_tags(['name__like' => 'Green']);
foreach($tags as $tag) {
    echo $tag['name'].'<br/>';
}
?>
```

Comment: WordPress utility code changes, so if you can, check the posting date on any site where you find such a listing. Here's a fairly recent page with code that may work for you: https://wpsites.net/wordpress-tips/display-list-of-tags/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace $tage['name'] with $tage->name and it will work fine.

```
<?php 
$tags = get_tags(['name__like' => 'green']);
foreach($tags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name.'<br/>';
}
?>
```

to display as links, use the function get_tag_link().

```
<?php
$tags = get_tags(['name__like' => 'Green']);

foreach($tags as $tag) {
    $tag_link = get_tag_link($tag->term_id); //this a url link
    echo '<div class="tags"><a href="'.$tag_link.'"> '.$tag->name.'</a> </div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. It's displaying, but not as links. How to display as links ?

Comment: Answer edited, as showen above, use get_tag_link() and pass the tag id($tag->term_id) as a parameter  to get a url link to the specified tag.